# How to get UID in Jenkins Pipeline job

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, ubuntu-16.04

How to access `UID` variable in Jenkins pipeline job?

I got `null` when do:

```groovy
pipeline {

    agent any
    environment {
        def userId = "${env.UID}";
    }
    stages {
        stage('Print UID') { 
            steps {
                script {
                   echo "${userId}"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Jenkins is hosted on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: What are you trying to capture? The user ID of the one triggering the job or the ID with which Jenkins is executing as?

Comment: The Jenkins user ID which is used on ubuntu system

Comment: @towel that's a completely different kind of user id.

Comment: @StopHarmingMonica right, I should've asked  Ravindranath's question before assuming anything else. I deleted my comment to prevent future confusion. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This code creates a local variable in the scope of the `environment` block.

From the [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment)  the `environment` dir uses "setter" style properties. You can change your code to:

```groovy
environment {
    userId = "${env.UID}";
}
```

This will make the environment variable `userId` available in the other parts of the pipeline (could be proven by performing a `sh 'env'` or something similar).

But, before that, I am not sure where `"${env.UID}"` comes from. If it is a plugin you have, then it will work great. If not, then you will have to figure out how to get the value you are expecting.

Answer (score 5):

you can use this code.

```
environment {
    userId = sh(script: "id -u ${USER}", returnStdout: true)
}
```

Comment: Actually, you should also call `.trim()` on that. Otherwise the `userId` variable will contain a line break at the end, which in turn may break your `sh` calls.